# How to call a powershell script to another powershell script with arguments?

Tags: powershell

I just need to call another script and pass the parameters to it.

I tried doing invoke-expression to access it, i tried using &, and nothing worked

I  tried doing the following:

```
 $hostfile = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\csvfile_test.csv"
 $outFile = ".\testerFile.xlsx"
 &  '.\organizer.ps1' "-csvFile $hostfile -outputPath $outFile "

Invoke-Expression 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\organizer.ps1' "$hostfile $outFile"
```

I receive the following errors:.

with ampersand (&):

```
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> C:\Users\username\Desktop\scanner.ps1
Exception calling "ReadLines" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\scanner.ps1:48 char:1
+ [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$csvFile") | ForEach-Object {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

with invoke-expression:

```
Exception calling "ReadLines" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\scanner.ps1:48 char:1
+ [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("$csvFile") | ForEach-Object {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException

Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\csvfile_test.csv .\testerFile.xlsx'.
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\scanner.ps1:69 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\organizer.ps1' "$host ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:

```
& '.\organizer.ps1' "-csvFile $hostfile -outputPath $outFile "
```

you are passing *a single parameter* to the script (one quoted string). That's not what you want.

This is what you need:

```
$hostfile = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\csvfile_test.csv"
$outFile = ".\testerFile.xlsx"
.\organizer.ps1 -csvFile $hostfile -outputPath $outFile
```

First, you don't need the `&` (invocation) operator because your command name (the `organizer.ps1` script in the current location, in this example) doesn't contain spaces. (You can add it if you want, but it's unnecessary in this scenario.)

Second, the `-csvFile` and `-outputPath` parameters each require a string.